# How to import a .hs file in Haskell

Tags: haskell, syntax, module

I have made a file called `time.hs`. It contains a single function that measures the execution time another function.

Is there a way to import the `time.hs` file into another Haskell script?

**I want something like:**

```
module Main where
import C:\Haskell\time.hs

main = do
    putStrLn "Starting..."
    time $ print answer
    putStrLn "Done."
```

**Where time is defined in the 'time.hs' as:**

```
module time where
Import <necessary modules>

time a = do
start <- getCPUTime
v <- a
end   <- getCPUTime
let diff = (fromIntegral (end - start)) / (10^12)
printf "Computation time: %0.3f sec\n" (diff :: Double)
return v
```

I don't know how to import or load a separate `.hs` file. Do I need to compile the `time.hs` file into a module before importing?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

`Time.hs`:

```
module Time where
...
```

`script.hs`:

```
import Time
...
```

Command line:

```
ghc --make script.hs
```

Comment: I learned the long way that in this example `script.hs` must be in your present working directory. This means you can't do `ghc --make path/to/script.hs`, for example.

Answer (score 16):

If the module `Time.hs` is located in the same directory as your "main" module, you can simply type:

```hs
import Time
```

It is possible to use a hierarchical structure, so that you can write `import Utils.Time`.
As far as I know, the way you want to do it won't work.

For more information on modules, see here [Learn You a Haskell, Making Our Own Modules](http://learnyouahaskell.com/modules#making-our-own-modules).

Answer (score 4):

Say I have two files in the same directory: ModuleA.hs and ModuleB.hs.

ModuleA.hs:

```
module ModuleA where
...
```

ModuleB.hs:

```
module ModuleB where

import ModuleA
...
```

I can do this:

```
    ghc -I. --make ModuleB.hs
```

**Note:** The module name and the file name must be the same. Otherwise it can't compile. Something like

> Could not find module '...'

will occur.